# $(document).ready(function () in asp.net mvc razor pages

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am calling $(document).ready(function () .. in my asp.net razor page (mvc) and when I create a breakpoint in chrome's javascript debugging tool, and it does not stop in there...

I don't understand whats wrong because it works when I use similar code in asp.net web forms.

Please help!

```
@model List<String>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Search for drink types";
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function () {
        $('#mi-slider').catslider();
        $('#carousel').elastislide({
            orientation: 'vertical'
        });
    });
    $(window).load(function () {
        $('#carousel1').carouFredSel({
            auto: false,
            prev: '.prev1',
            next: '.next1',
            width: 220,
            items: {
                visible: {
                    min: 1,
                    max: 1
                },
                height: 'auto',
                width: 220,
            },
            responsive: true,
            scroll: 1,
            mousewheel: false,
            swipe: {
                onMouse: false,
                onTouch: false
            }
        });
    });
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $().UItoTop({
            easingType: 'easeOutQuart'
        });
    });
</script>



@section featured {
    <section>
        <p>
            @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create", "Cocktails")
        </p>
    </section>
```

Comment: please, take a look in the source code, do you have attached jQuery library on the page?

Comment: @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/carousel") in my page

Comment: bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/carousel").Include(
               "~/js/jquery.js",
.......... etc in my bundleconfig

Comment: Is there an error in your browser's JavaScript console?  A difference in server-side technology has *no* impact on client-side functionality.  I assure you that JavaScript still works in ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: @Lilz, I mean source code in the browser, if you do not see jQuery library you need to add @{Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";} as I do not see definition of layout at the top of your page.

Comment: on one page there can only one $(window).load(function () {}...

Comment: @Lilz - I believe order matters when loading your scripts.  I would imagine jquery should be the first item in that bundle in order for the bundling processor to render them in the correct order.  Also, ensure you are outputting your bundles prior to any calls to items in those bundles (carosel, jquery, etc)

Comment: @Exception: Not correct. You can call `$(window).load()` as many times as you care to.

Comment: @ChrisPratt..No window.load can only be one on a page ... just check it over here..http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/951850-how-use-windows-onload-fuction-twice-same-page

Comment: if you want multiple window.load() then you have to make event listeners..check it here...http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/951850-how-use-windows-onload-fuction-twice-same-page

Comment: @Kartikeya: You are confusing `window.onload` with the jQuery implementation of `$(window).load()` used here *which allows as many handlers as you like* as they are combined within jQuery: e.g. try this http://jsfiddle.net/o90n6L15/ :)

Comment: If you place all your Javascript into a separate JS file and include that, you will be able to break-point it within Visual Studio (later versions at least). Your code break-points fine in a JSFiddle, so it is more likely a required file is missing. Can't really tell without all the source code.